How to Indent (tab) one specific line?
I want to indent one line, how would I do that?
For instance:
not indented
\{Some Command} Indented


Try to replace \{Some Command} with \par\noindent\hspace*{<len>} where you can specify the <len> to suit your needs (see What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?).

There are not enough context to answer concretely.
Indentation of first line paragraphs normally is the \parindent length and this can be changed in the preamble or anywhere in the text.  By default this indentation in  omitted  after section titles, but this can be changed by indentfirst of babel when is the usual in the language used. And indentation can be avoided locally with \noindent or increased with some like \hspace*{3cm} or making king an empty box (e.g. \makebox{3cm}{}).
If for some reason the indentation should be inside a paragraph and not it the first line, as Werner commented, one simple solution, is change this scenario and end the paragraph in the previous line inserting  \par or a blank line. This could work or produce an awful ragged margin (because there was some extra spaces in the previous line)  or insert also an unwanted vertical space (because \parskip is not 0pt). In this case  you can force a \linebreak (find the right point is up to you)  and add some horizontal space (not a true indentation) yourself. Note that \hspace without the asterik can be ignored if LaTeX think that have not sense in that place (e.g. in foo\\\hspace{4cm}bar). An example showing some of these scenarios:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Inside the paragraph}
% not nice, the right place for line break is up to you
\lipsum[1][1-2] \linebreak \hspace*{4cm} \lipsum[1][3-4]  
\subsubsection*{Outside the paragraph:}
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par\noindent\hspace*{4cm}  \lipsum[1][3-4] 
\setlength\parindent{4cm}
\subsubsection*{For every next paragraph execpt first:}
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par  \lipsum[1][3-4]\par  
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par  \lipsum[1][3-4]\par  
\makeatletter\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue\makeatother
% for all the document, just load the package indentfirst or set babel properly
\subsubsection*{By default even  in first paragraph}
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par  \lipsum[1][3-4]\par  
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par  \lipsum[1][3-4]\par  
\end{document}

